# Python selenium code to push a button is not working

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to click a button with python and selenium.

The html is this:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle no-opacity" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">
<span class="fa fa-lock fa-empty14px"></span>
<span class="strong">LOGIN</span>
</button>
```

I'm using this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://skovbakken.halbooking.dk/newlook/default.asp")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.navbar-toggle.no-opacity').click()
```

I't doesn't work. I get the response:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

Any help is appreciated.
Beste regards
Kresten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This button is hidden. You actually need to handle another element which is a link with text `"LOGIN"`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://skovbakken.halbooking.dk/newlook/default.asp")
driver.find_element_by_link_text('LOGIN').click()
```